# Converting JMeter scripts for Visual Studio use (Locally Hosted)

Tags: visual-studio, jmeter

A developer that I have engaged to code a system (java) will be providing their testing reports and scripts for our review. Scripts will be JMeter, I am wanting to gain a robust converter to enable these scripts to be used in for functional testing in a Locally Hosted Visual Studio instance running Microsoft 10.

What have people used previously?

Regards, Karen

Answer (score 0):

Performance scripts are not meant for functional testing as they dont have the interaction capabilities with the page objects like click. So, jmeter scripts are not 100% equivalent to functional testing.

If you want to use the jmeter jmx with Visual Studio then you can do it as VS allows to run the jmx. Check the below reference:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts

Hope this helps.